# App.config relative path

Tags: c#, app-config

I have folder "Icons".
I need to access same in order to add an icon to `imageList`.
I'm using app.config file in that have a relative path.

```
<add key="doc" value="..\Icons\_Microsoft Office Excel 97-2003 Worksheet.ico" />
```

and I'm using below code to add it to `imgList` ,however it throws `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`:

```
smallImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["doc"]));
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 8):

Try adding the current running path:

```
smallImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["doc"])));
```

Comment: Thanks for that , that working ..even 
Path.GetFullPath(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["doc"]); this works..i wanted to know is im doin something wrong in 
smallImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["doc"]));

Comment: smallImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(Path.GetFullPath(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["doc"])));

Comment: This should have been marked as the answer. The problem seemed to be that `Image.FromFile` expects an absolute path, not a relative one.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to concatenate that with System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.

I'd guess that FromFile is relative to the current working directory which is prone to change.  The other thing to consider would be embedding the images in the assembly

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that one. much much simpler that my GetExecutingAssembly() solution...

Answer (score 2):

Go to properties , find 'Copy to Output Directory' property and choose "Copy always" . Then it should be fine. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tilda...

```
value="~\Icons_Microsoft Office Excel 97-2003 Worksheet.ico"
```

Which should start you from the application root.

Answer (score 0):

Your working folder has somehow been modified during your program execution, you have to find your own path.

Try this:

```
using System.Reflection;
string CurrDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

smallImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(CurrDirectory,ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["doc"])));
```

Comment: hi Vinzz,

it retrieves the path 
C:\Documents and Settings\ADMIN\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\IconsLoadinginTreeview_Files_Demo\IconsLoadinginTreeview_Files_Demo\bin\Debug\..\Icons\_Microsoft Office Excel 97-2003 Worksheet.ico 


".."  in the filPath again throwing error

Comment: Of course, your mileage may vary. Add an extra '..' there or there if necessary. I don't know where your icons really are ;o) Btw, it seems you already found a solution, isn't it?